# Gif image looping only once

Tags: c#, animated-gif

I was trying to figure out how to make sure that a `GIF image` what I put to my WindowsForm project through `picturebox` going to loop only once and still without finding an answer even after going through as many sites with this problem as I could find.

I know that with using of picturebox programmer lossing control of looping (in case that you set looping only once when creating the gif animation in editor) and I somehow have to get a code which will basically say when gif animation gets to some certain frame...in my case to last one which is number 7 and gets there in 430 milliseconds (190,40,40,40,40,40,40) the gif animation going to be Disposed.

So the whole idea was to make a simple game with balloons which will have an animation with flying and animation with exploding after pressing of the mouse on the ballon_grey picture box.

It would look like that:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //makes balloon going up
    balloon_grey.Location = new Point(balloon_grey.Location.X, balloon_grey.Location.Y - 3);     
}

private void balloon_grey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //forces balloon_grey picturebox to change animation to balloon_grey_explosion.gif
    balloon_grey.Image = Image.FromFile("balloon_grey_explosion.gif");

    //gets the amount of frames from the gif animation...don't know if this is needed to reach the goal
    int frames = Properties.Resources.balloon_grey_explosion.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Time);
}
```

Thank you for your time and any advice about the problem.

Comment: check your image `balloon_grey_explosion.gif` in a internet browser.. if it is looping or not..

Comment: You'll have to give up on PictureBox if you want to do this.  And fall back to the basics.  A Timer to decide to change the frame, Graphics.DrawImage() to paint it (like in the form's Paint event), Image.GetFrameCount() to discover how many frames are in the GIF, Image.SelectActiveFrame() to select the next frame.

Comment: I checked it in a browser and it loops only once since I set it in editor during making of the GIF file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm programming in VB.NET and I hope this can be useful to you, once you've figured out how to program it in C#.

This will stop the loop in the frame you choose, in my example is in frame 18:

```
    Dim gif As Image = PictureBox3.Image
    Dim fd As New Imaging.FrameDimension(gif.FrameDimensionsList()(0))
    gif.SelectActiveFrame(fd, 18)
    PictureBox3.Enabled = False
```